# What's the aim of not used java keyword?

Tags: java, standards, keyword

As [oracle states](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), const is a keyword in java. But it is **not used**. So why is it so and what's the use of **const** being a non used keyword in java? (the same goes for **goto**)

Comment: I would assume that the goal was to discourage people from using them as identifiers. Otherwise people would be naming things `const` and `goto`, and then wonder why it's doing something completely different from other platforms.

Comment: There's a nice little thread about what use (if any) they might put const to in the future here: http://forums.java.net/node/667677 . Personally, I doubt it will ever be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

> The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used.
>   This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords
>   incorrectly appear in programs.

(This wording already was in the first edition, I think.)

Answer (score 2):

To reserved for future usages.

This way, if that keyword is needed in the future, there won't be source code using them, and no code would be break.

For instance, have java had the word `in` as reserved, the [enhanced for loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) introducen in Java 5 could have been written as:

```
for( int i in someInts ) { 
}
```

But since it wasn't we have:

```
for( int i : someInts ) { 
}
```

Instead ( which I think is nicer btw )

Comment: As for `goto` I don't really think it will be used in the future, but remains reserved to avoid using it in source code.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes words are reserved for future purposes. That's most likely the case here.